DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion
I created a small Swift app using Xcode 15.4 on macOS 14.6.1 (I have since updated to Xcode 16 + macOS 15.0, no change to the behavior). The code is pretty boilerplate, just a simple screencapture app using ScreenCaptureKit. The app builds and runs successfully with no errors. The app's name is kitkap.
My question is, when compiling in Terminal with
xcodebuild -target kitkap -configuration Release

...I get the following "error" output:
DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion.

Googling revealed practically nothing about this mysterious error. Does anyone know what it means or how to supply the proper "DVTBuildVersion"?
Here are some screenshots that might be illustrative:



Just had this error when testing for specific destinations, this is kinda strange indeed.
Our problem resided in the target destination being bugged.
We were testing for an iPhone 14 with the flag: -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14'
We listed our devices with xcrun simctl list devices and then deleted it with xcrun simctl delete <device udid> as seen in this post.
After recreating the run destination, our xcodebuild test command returned to work.

FYI, I struggled with this issue for a few hours, but somehow I fixed it.  I followed the instructions from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78681786/1424762 and that just somehow magically cleared up my problem.
Don't know how Allowing Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules clear this problem up, but there's a lot of other things I don't underestand.  ‍♂️
Hope this is helpful to others, too.
You can find this higlighted in the picture below:


I can't find that setting anywhere - where is it exactly? (Xcode 16)

@luckman212, I added a screenshot of Xcode above.  You can see under Apple Clang - Launguage - Modules under the BuildSettings tab.  Hope that helps.

Thanks, but I tried that in my own project (for reference, the corresponding key in the .xcodeproj file is CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES) and it did not silence these warnings.

In my case, I was building a C++ library using CMake for the Xcode generator. While the error I got in the console was about DVTBuildVersion, it was actually a compile error in the library when I opened the underlying generated Xcode project and built it.
In this case, a Xcode was being strict about an implicit cast.
Resolving that error removed the issue about DVTBuildVersion.
