Flutter building for iOS: Error output from Xcode build + DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion
When i try to build Flutter app to ios i get this error
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           111.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2024-10-06 23:59:32.467 xcodebuild[35990:3039730]  DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion.
    2024-10-06 23:59:33.181 xcodebuild[35990:3039672] [MT] DVTDeviceOperation: Encountered a build number "" that is incompatible with DVTBuildVersion.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


I have tried deleting:

pods, podfile, podfile.lock, pubspec.lock, .symlink
flutter clean, flutter upgrade, flutter pub get
modifying the version in pubspec and xcode manually
adding this in podfile

   installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end  


allowing non modular includes in xcode


I have tried solutions from here and didnt work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78850571/dvtdeviceoperation-encountered-a-build-number-that-is-incompatible-with-dvtbuil

I'm facing the same problem.
I'm using the 3.22.3 Flutter version and the Sonoma OS version.

I was facing the same problem as you, and I could run the app after updating the Cocoapods to version 1.16.2. To do that, run the command below in your terminal.

sudo gem install cocoapods

